# Simulate a series of code n(lets say 1000) times while saving the result in a vector in R

Tags: r, simulation

I'm still relatively new to R so I'm struggling with repeating lines of code several times and saving the result for each repetition.

The aim is to randomly (equal probability) assign a number of events, in my case 100, over a 20 year period. Since days are irrelevant I use the number of months to define the period. Subsequently, I'm counting the events for every 24-month period within the 20 years. Lastly, extracting the maximum number of events occurring within a 24-month period.

Albeit messy and probably inefficient, the code works for the intended purpose. However, I want to repeat this process 1000 times to get a distribution of all the maximum number of events taking place over 24 months to compare to my real data.

here is my coding so far:

```
library(runner)
library(dplyr)

#First I set the period from the year 2000 to 2019 with one-month increments. 
period <- seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 240)

#I sample random observations assigned to different months over the entire period. 
u <- sample(period, size=100, replace=T)

#Make a table in order to register the number of occurrences within each month. 
u <- table(u)

#Create a data frame to ease information processing. 
simulation <- data.frame(u)

#Change the date column to date format. 
simulation$u <- as.Date(simulation$u)

#Compute number of events taking place within every 24-month period (730 = days in 24 months). 
u <- u %>%
  mutate(
    Last_24_month_total = sum_run(
      x = simulation$Freq, 
      k = 730, 
      idx = as.Date(simulation$u, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
  )

#extract the maximum number of uccurences within a 24 month period
max <- max(u$Last_24_month_total)
```

Could someone help me understand how to rewrite this process in order to facilitate a thousand repetitions while saving the max value for each repetition?
thanks

Comment: eventually you can use `replicate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jogo suggested in the comments, you can use `replicate`.

I simplified your code.

```
library(runner)
library(dplyr)

seq_dates <- seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 240)

replicate(100,
          seq_dates %>% 
           sample(100, replace = TRUE) %>% 
           table() %>% 
           sum_run(730, idx = as.Date(names(.))) %>% 
           max)
```